# form input path with option value in html

Tags: html, forms, jsp, input, html-select

So I'm doing this pc building workshop sim in spring framework (via eclipse ee with mysql db connection) and I'm curently trying to edit my add_configuration.jsp so that you can select from a list of components the one you want to chose, and that choice will be stored in the database.
Here is my curent code that i use for input

```
                <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pc/pc-add-save.htm" method="post" commandName="pcForm">
            CPU: <form:input path="cpu"/><br/>
            Motherboard: <form:input path="motherboard"/><br/>
            RAM: <form:input path="ram"/><br/>
            Storage: <form:input path="storage"/><br/>
            GPU: <form:input path="gpu"/><br/>
            Power Supply: <form:input path="pw"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save config"/><br/>
            </form:form>
```

and  here is how I would like it to be:

```
                <select id="ram">
                  <option value="2 GB">Volvo</option>
                  <option value="4 GB">Saab</option>
                  <option value="8GB">Opel</option>
                  <option value="16 GB">Audi</option>
                </select>
```

How can transform the first code to do the thing the second one does?

Sorry for eventual mistakes or for not offering enough details, it's my first stackoverflow post :)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606019/how-correctly-use-the-spring-mvc-formselect-tag-to-show-the-value-of-a-specif) post it will help you to achieve above .

Comment: Thanks, i also found the answer in a spring mvc book :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it myself, this is how the cood needs to look like to work

```
<form:select path="cpu">
                <form:option value="i7-9700K (9th Gen)" label="i7-9700K (9th Gen)" />
                <form:option value="AMD Ryzen 9 3950X" label="AMD Ryzen 9 3950X" />
                <form:option value="AMD Ryzen 7 3700X" label="AMD Ryzen 7 3700X" />
                    </form:select>
```